# Reset built-in constants

Tags: python-2.7

While running a Python 2.7 interpreter, I assigned `False` to `True`. Is there a way to reset `True` to its original value without restarting the interpreter? (Assume there isn't any user defined explicit reference available to the original `True` in the interpreter environment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
True = (1 == 1)
```

Note:

```
>>> True = False
>>> True
False
>>> True and True
False
>>> True = (1 == 1)
>>> True
True
>>> True and True
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it from the `__builtin__` module:

```
import __builtin__
True = __builtin__.True
```

so that:

```
import __builtin__
True = False
print(True)
True = __builtin__.True
print(True)
```

would output:

```
False
True
```